# django rest framework customize serializer

Tags: django, serialization, django-rest-framework

My models are Purchase, Item, ItemGroup, Store

These are the relevant fields of the models:

```
class Store(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class ItemGroup(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    store = models.ForeignKey(Store)

class Item(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    group = models.ForeignKey(ItemGroup)

class Purchase(models.Model):
    item = models.ForeignKey(Item)
    date = models.DateTimeField()
```

I want to write a serializer for Purchase.
For each purchase, I want the following output:

```
{"item": "item_name", "store": "store_name"}
```

(Also there are some additional Purcahse fields, but these are easy to fetch).

I've tried to follow the relations using the django double underscore `__` style, but this does not work:

```
class PurchaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = ('item', 'item__group__store')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class PurchaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    store = serializers.CharField(source="item.group.store.name")
    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = ('item', 'store')
```

Remember to prefetch store for requests optimization.

Answer (score 1):

Use [**`source`**](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/fields/#source) argument

```
class PurchaseSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    item = serializers.CharField(source='item.name')
    store = serializers.CharField(source="item.group.store.name")

    class Meta:
        model = Purchase
        fields = ('item', 'store')
```